# How to import a function from a Javascript module that wasn't declared

Tags: typescript

I'm using a third party Javascript library that has Typescript type declarations (`.d.ts`). As is very often the case, the type declarations are wrong. In this case they are missing a function. I would like to do

```
import { foo } from "lib";
```

But Typescript correctly complains that `foo` does not exist in `lib`. How do I tell it that it does and import it? I tried creating a `shims.d.ts` file that contains this:

```
declare module "lib" {
  // This function is missing from the Typescript declarations.
  export function foo(): void;
}
```

That works but then I can't import any of the things that *are* correctly declared in `lib`.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I was close! It seems to work with this in any `.d.ts` file.

```
import "lib"
declare module "lib" {
  // This function is missing from the Typescript declarations.
  export function foo(): void;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the library is open source, your best bet is:

1. Fork the repo
2. Fix the typing to include `foo`
3. Do a pull request

Use your fork until/unless the pull request is accepted.